# Single driver instance using cucumber-jvm testng with maven

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I was using junit as my testing framework with cucumber-jvm, selenium page factory pattern and maven. Now i have requirement to change it to Testng to execute parallel. Most of the blog says add extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests in the runner class. but when i do that. I am getting nullpointer exception.

Can someone share your approach using testng with cucumber?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone share your approach using testng with cucumber?

Teach a man to fish and all that. What I do when I have questions like this is to go the cucumber-jvm [example page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples).

Take a look at [java-calculator-testng](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-calculator-testng).

Try to implement this sample project locally on your computer and get it working.  Now that you have a working example extended it to do what you need to be done.

I hope this helped.  A full example would take a lot of space.